# Мини соц сеть на Джанго. Редактирование поста

Tags: python, django

[image: Код ошибки приложил]Создаю мини соц сеть на Джанго. Нужно чтобы после редактирования поста пост изменялся и сохранялся в бд. Также нужен редирект на страницу поста после этого. Но вместо того, чтоб в этом посте появлялись изменения, появляется новый пост (и в нем присутствуют внесённые изменения). Но и старый, который я по сути и редактировал, тоже остается и не изменяется. А редирект приводит на главную страницу. В чем может быть проблема?

Функция вью файла:

```
def post_edit(request, username, post_id):
    print('Редактирую')
    author = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, author=author)
    login_author = request.user
    if login_author != author:
        return redirect('post', username=author.username, post_id=post.id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post.save()
        return redirect('post', username=request.user.username, post_id=user_post.id)
    return render(request, 'new_post.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
```

Шаблон:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{% if not post %} Добавить запись {% else %} Редактировать запись {% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% load user_filters%}

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 p-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{% if not post %} Добавить запись {% else %} Редактировать запись {% endif %}</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                    {% for error in form.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {{ error }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                <form method="post" action="{% url 'new_post' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="form-group row" aria-required={% if field.field.required %}"true"{% else %}"false"{% endif %}>
                                <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {{ field|addclass:"form-control" }}
                                    {% if field.help_text %}
                                    <small id="{{ field.id_for_label }}-help" class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">              
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {% if post %} Сохранить {% else %} Добавить {% endif %}
                            </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- card body -->
        </div> <!-- card -->
    </div> <!-- col -->
</div> <!-- row -->

{% endblock %}
```

Если в шаблон добавляю условие:

```
<form method="post" action={% if post %} "{% url 'post_edit'  %}" {% else %} "{% url 'new_post' %}" {% endif %}>
```

То появляется ошибка.

urls:

from django.urls import path

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("group/<slug:slug>/", views.group_posts, name="group_posts"),
    path("new/", views.new_post, name="new_post"),
    # Профайл пользователя
    path('<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    # Просмотр записи
    path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/', views.post_view, name='post'),
    # edit
    path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

Comment: Похоже проблема в том, что url `{% url 'post_edit'  %}` должен принять еще параметр `post.id`, (+ username, судя по `post_edit` view) но что бы точно сказать, добавь urls.py

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ) добавил urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не против, я походу дела заодно немного оптимизирую ваш код (на мой скромный взгляд).

```py
#views.py

def post_edit(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user is not post.author:
            return redirect('post', post_id=post.id)
        form = PostForm(instance=post)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('post', post_id=post.id)

    return render(request, 'create_or_update_post.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
```

Что изменилось?

- Я не увидел особого смысла передавать переменную `username` в представление. Чтобы получить объект `post` вам с головой хватит поля `id`, поскольку оно уникально для каждой записи. Если вам оно нравится, то просто верните обратно
- Переменные `author` и `login_author` бесполезны – выкидываем
- Разделил методы на `GET` и `POST`
- когда вы сохраняете данные в методе `is_valid`, то почему-то сохраняете запись `post`, а не саму форму
- После сохранения формы, вы перенаправляете пользователя на эту статью, но в качестве аргумента в `redirect()` передаете `post_id=user_post.id`. Что такое `user_post' и откуда оно взялось? Вы не объявляли эту переменную и не передавали ее в представление
- Ну и косметическое замечание: старайтесь называть вещи своими именами. Ваш шаблон `new_post.html` предназначен не только для создания нового поста, но и для его редактирования

```html
#create_or_update_post.html

...
<form method="post" action={% if post %}"{% url 'post_edit' post_id=post.id %}"{% else %}"{% url 'new_post' %}"{% endif %}>
...
```

До этого форма сохранялась каждый раз как новая, потому что вы отправляли ее в представление `new_post`, а не `edit_post`. Вы правильно придумали с проверкой условия, но не передали в url обязательные аргументы

Comment: я бы, так же, убрал проверку `if request.user is not post.author:`, вместо этого при получении объекта добавил бы  `post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, author=request.user)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, поправил, все работает!))